# Extending Devise integration test helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, minitest

Devise provides `Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers` for testing purposes. The [documentation](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/lib/devise/test/integration_helpers.rb) defines a helper method for signing in but forces a nil to the basic method `login_as` scope.

```
# Signs in a specific resource, mimicking a successful sign in operation through +Devise::SessionsController#create+.
# * +resource+ - The resource that should be authenticated
# * +scope+    - An optional +Symbol+ with the scope where the resource should be signed in with.

def sign_in(resource, scope: nil)
  scope ||= Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource)

  login_as(resource, scope: scope)
end
```

The goal is to create a helper method that will login with a host scope, where `host`is an attribute of the `Site` class and thus a fixture ( i.e. sites(:one) )

However, `login_as` is a method internal to devise and not accessible to the testing enviornment AFAIK.

What helper method could be written to set a host upon sign_in ?

Comment: You're making a very wrong assumption here - login_as is not an internal Devise method. It's provided by Warden::Test::Helpers and you just need to include it to have access to the method. https://www.rubydoc.info/github/hassox/warden/Warden/Test/Helpers